# OCaml main function

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, program-entry-point

I need a main function to run the others functions.

I tried this:

```
let main () = 
  let deck = make_mazo in 
  let jugadores = players [] 0 in
  dothemagic deck jugadores 0 [] [] [];;
```

But I got this error:

> File "game.ml", line 329, characters 37-39:
>   Error: Syntax error

I think `;;` is the problem and I need a different way to end the code. Also try with only `;` and the problem is the same.

## [EDIT]

#### An update here

```
let main = 
  let deck = make_mazo [] in 
  let game = players deck [] 0 in
  let dd = fst game in 
  let jugadores = snd game in
  dothemagic dd jugadores 0 [] [] [] [];

let () = main;;
```

Error persist:

> File "game.ml", line 253, characters 13-15:
>   Error: Syntax error

The other functions are working perfectly fine, but i need a main function because I want to run the program with `ocaml game.ml` or `ocamlbuild game.native`

## [SECOND EDIT]

After @camlspotter response: The use of `;` of your code is wrong. Remove it.

#### Update 2.0

```
let main = 
  let deck = make_mazo [] in 
  let game = players deck [] 0 in
  let dd = fst game in 
  let jugadores = snd game in
  dothemagic dd jugadores 0 [] [] [] []

let () = main;;
```

New Error:

> File "game.ml", line 253, characters 0-3: Error: Syntax error

Think `let` is the problem now, so i try with this

```
let main = 
  let deck = make_mazo [] in 
  let game = players deck [] 0 in
  let dd = fst game in 
  let jugadores = snd game in
  dothemagic dd jugadores 0 [] [] [] []

main;;
```

But Error is:

> File "game.ml", line 253, characters 4-6:
>   Error: Syntax error

Comment: Another "card game class exercise question" without enough information to answer.  Please post a code with which the community can reproduce your problem. If the code is big, try to minimize it.

Comment: The invasion of spanish card games is real !

Comment: The use of `;` of your code is wrong.  Remove it.

Comment: what exactly line 253, char 4-6 is refering to ?

Comment: The line 253 is `main;;` so char 4-6 is `;;`

Comment: Your second edit is totally wrong.  As Jeffery has already pointed out, the problem is NOT in the part you show us.  I REPEAT.  Post a complete code which we can reproduce your problem.  If the code is too large, try to minimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I had to write the functions in the following way,

```
let fun x =
let y = blabla in
code_returning_unit; (* Use ; for unit returns *)
return_value;; (* Use ;; for end of fun *)
```

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with the code you show here.

Most likely the problem is near the end of the part you don't show, like around line 324 of the file.

If I had to guess, I'd say that line 324 ends with `in` :-)

As a side comment, you'll also need to *call* this main function. You might want the last line of the file to be something like this:

```
let () = main ()
```

(This line appears in many of my OCaml projects.)

Answer (score 1):

OCaml programs, unlike programs in many other languages, do not have a specific entry-point: all the code in a module (file) is evaluated in order from top to bottom, sort of like in a scripting language. A common idiom you'll see is:

```
let name = "World" (* I could have added a ;; at the
                    * end of this line, but that would
                    * have been unnecessary *)

let () =
  Printf.printf "Hello, %s!\n" name
```

which will output

```
Hello, World!
```

The `let () = ...` may seem a bit wonky, but it's really just pattern-matching: the return type of `Printf.printf` is unit, `()` is also of type `unit`, the you're really just saying "match this `unit` value with the result of evaluating this expression". Basically, this idiom means "run this unit-type expression in a safe way".

A similar, although highly discouraged, idiom, uses the catch-all pattern:

```
let greet s =
  match s with
  | "" -> false
  | _ ->
      Printf.printf "Hello, %s!\n" s;
      true

let name = "World"

let _ =
  greet world
```

The catch-all pattern doesn't care about the type (or value) of the expression it's being matched against, and this idiom means "run this expression and discard whatever it returned".

Comment: Thanks my problem was one line returning unit without `;`

Answer (score 0):

In ocaml, there is no main function unlike other languages, see the code below :

```
let () = print_string "hello\n";;
let f = print_string "hello, this is f\n";;
let () = f;;
```